# Preferred way to populate properties of a class?

Tags: vb.net, object, constructor

Is anything wrong with populating a class type's propertie values by passing that class into a constructor of another class

See example code where GetData's Constructor takes a Data object ByRef and populates it.  Would it make more sense or be preferred to have a separate method Function in class GetData that populates and returns the Data Object and its values or is it OK to pass it in to the constructor like the example code demonstrates?

```
Public Class Data

   Public Property Value1 As String
   Public Property Value2 As String

End Class
```

'

```
Public Class GetData

   Public Sub New(ByRef data As Data)
       data.Value1 = "a"
       data.Value2 = "b"
   End Sub

End Class
```

'

```
Private Sub PopulateData()

    Dim data As New Data
    Dim gd As New GetData(data)


End Sub
```

Comment: How about None of the Above.  `Public Property Value1 As String = "a"`

Comment: I like your example. Possibly I could have worded my question different. My issue is more complex than my example reveals. I have situations where I need to get a Class Type from a class. I find myself frequently passing a Class Type to another Class's Constructor (ByRef) and letting that Constructor populate the Class that was passed to it.  Would be a better practice to have a Function create, populate and return the Class Type instead?

Comment: Never would I outsource variable initialization to another class.  It breaks encapsulation and makes it more complicated.

Comment: Passing a class type. It seems you need to use generic `(Of T)`.